# How to prove the singularity of a variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, singularity

Consider the Veronese map $\mathbb{P}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^{5}$ and let $X\subset\mathbb{P}^{5}$ be the cubic hypersurface defined by $\det(A)=0$.
Now $X$ is the image of all reducible conics.

I want to prove that $Sing(X)=\{[A]\subset\mathbb{P}^{5}\mid rk(A)=1\}$, which is indeed the image of reduced conics. What should I do?

Then, as a consequence, I think I would have that if $X\subset\mathbb{P}^{n}$ is a hypersurface of degree $d\geq1$ containing $L$ linear subspace with $dim L\geq\frac{n}{2}$, then $X$ is singular. Which is the statement I initially wanted to prove.

I tried to prove directly the second statement, considering $I=\left\{(p,[F])\mid p\in V\left(F,\dfrac {\partial F}{\partial x_0}, \dots, \dfrac {\partial F}{\partial x_n}\right)\right\}$ and trying to show that $\dim I\geq0$,but I didn't succeed.

Comment: What is the matrix $A$?

Comment: Via the Veronese map, you can see $P^{5}$ as $P$(Symmetric matrices 3x3). Take $p$ = ($x_{0}, x_{1}, x_{2}$), its image in $P^{5}$ is ($x_{0}^{2}$, $x_{0}x_{1}$, $x_{0}x_{2}$, $x_{1}^{2}$, $x_{1}x_{2}$, $x_{2}^{2}$) and we can associate at these coordinates in $P^{5}$ a symmetric matrix that i called A.

Comment: Did you try to compute the formal partial derivation of $\det A$?